# why am I getting "Error 403: AuthorizationFailed" in this simple WebSphere example web.xml?

Tags: java, authentication, websphere, web.xml

I'm using WebSphere 7.  I have a simple example set up with web.xml as shown below.

This is how I test it:

1. I start with no user and no group in WebSphere
2. I try to access the page (/restricted/topsecret.html) I'm prompted to log in.  I cannot.
3. I add a user/password "rob/password" using the WebSphere admin console.  I can now log in, but I cannot see the page.  I get a "403: AuthorizationFailed" error.
4. I add a group called "ROLE1" and I assign that group to user "rob" using the WebSphere admin console.  I restart firefox, I can still log in but I still get the "403" error.
5. I wrote a little JSP (below) to output the logged in username, but even after logging the username is still null.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??  Thanks!

Rob

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>page test 1</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/restricted/topsecret.html</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>ROLE1</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

usertest.jsp

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
Logged in username = '<%= request.getRemoteUser() %>' // is always null
<p/>
Logged in username = '<%= request.getUserPrincipal() %>' // is always null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three levels of security

1. Administration level
2. Application Level
3. Java 2 Level

I am assuming you have turned on Application level (it sounds like you have it turned on but I would want to check)

Is the usertest.jsp secured?

Did you restart the application after mapping Roles to users?

The code in the JSP (the first line doesn't look good syntactically. I am assuming a typo)

Comment: Administration and Application level are on. Java 2 Level is off. Is that right?  No, usertest.jsp was not secured; I try to visit it after logging in on a secured page.  Yes, I restarted the app after adding Roles.  Yes a typo, corrected, thanks.

Comment: FYI, I discoverd a different (related) problem.  I posted a new question that focuses on it, here's the link -- please help if you can, thanks! -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725362/why-doesnt-the-websphere-7-console-save-directly-to-master-configuration-ap

Answer (score 0):

This is for WAS 7. I recently faced this issue with our application throwing 403 Error.

```
 ibm-application-bnd.xml
<security-role name="DefaultRole">
        <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" /></security-role>
    <security-role name="NoSecurity">
        <special-subject type="EVERYONE" /></security-role></application-bnd>
```

application.xml

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>DefaultRole</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>NoSecurity</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Check both the xml files